# databind a gridview populated in the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I have tried a lot and have reached a dead end.

I have a to show multiple gridviews on one page and all these are getting populated dynamically.

i have figured a way to populate the gridview dynamically and display them, but i cannot get how to modify  these values and display them as i want.

here is the code. for .aspx page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars ="Auto" Height="500px" BorderColor="#003399" BorderWidth="3px">


</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

and here is the code for .aspx.cs

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            GridView Grid = new GridView();
            ArrayList machID = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList machName = new ArrayList();


            Grid.ID = machGrps[j].ToString();
            Grid.AllowSorting = true;
            Grid.CellSpacing = 2;
            Grid.GridLines = GridLines.None;
            Grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Session["ConnectionStringSQL"].ToString());
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select MachineID, MachineName from Machines", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            connection.Close();

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    machID.Add(dt.Rows[i]["MachineID"].ToString());
                    machName.Add(dt.Rows[i]["MachineName"].ToString());

                }

                DataTable taskTable = new DataTable();
                taskTable.Columns.Add("MachineID");
                taskTable.Columns.Add("MachineName");

                if (machID.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < machID.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();
                        tableRow["MachineID"] = machID[i];
                        tableRow["MachineName"] = machName[i];

                        taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                    }
                }                  


                Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

                Grid.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
                Grid.DataBind();

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = "Machine Grp" + Grid.ID;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(label);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(Grid);

            }
        }
```

NOTE THIS CODE BELOW CANNOT BE DONE ANYMORE AS I POPULATE THE GRIDVIEW DIRECTLY FROM THE TABLES:

I used to modify like this when the ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound" if is called from the .aspx page

the databound code looks like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow myRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            //this is where ID is stored in an label template
            Label Label3 = (Label)myRow.FindControl("Label3");
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text);

            Image Image5 = (Image)myRow.FindControl("Image5");
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text) < 0)
            {
                Image5.ImageUrl = "~/NewFolder1/warning_16x16.gif";
            }
            else
            {
                Image5.ImageUrl = "~/NewFolder1/1258341827_tick.png";
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (GridViewRow myRow in GridView1.Rows) {
      // blah blah blah code goes here  
    }
}
```

should be

```
//now e is a 
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        // blah blah blah, this lets you work on one row at a time.
        // since the framework does this per row, you don't need to parse the gridview
        // yourself, altho you're more than welcome to.
        // But you can get more control this way. I promise.
        Label Label3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label3");
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text);

        Image Image5 = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image5");
        if (val < 0)
        {
            Image5.ImageUrl = "~/NewFolder1/warning_16x16.gif";
        }
        else
        {
            Image5.ImageUrl = "~/NewFolder1/1258341827_tick.png";
        }

        // alternately write the code above like this:
        Image Image5 = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image5");
        Image5.ImageUrl = (val < 0) ? "~/NewFolder1/warning_16x16.gif" : "~/NewFolder1/1258341827_tick.png";
        // that's called the ternary operator. Takes up less space, does the same thing.
    }
}
```

## Please don't ignore this part

Now to the other part, are you aware that you can still bind in the backside like thus:

```
GridView1.RowDataBound += GridView1_RowDataBound;
```

Put it here:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        GridView Grid = new GridView();
        ArrayList machID = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList machName = new ArrayList();

        //NEW LINE (doesn't need the comment or the blank space tho)
        Grid.RowDataBound += Grid_RowDataBound;

        Grid.ID = machGrps[j].ToString();
        Grid.AllowSorting = true;
        Grid.CellSpacing = 2;
        Grid.GridLines = GridLines.None;
        Grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
```

Comment: e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow as you say will take the entire row but how do i modify the value in that row.. as u can see i have populated this dynamically. I mean first i had the label to look for because it contained the ID but now i dont have nay label to find

Comment: drachenstern.. this is what i am saying that there is no Label 3 control as there i did not create the gridview in the HTML page so when it tries to do this "Label Label3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label3");" it wil get nothing.

Comment: @user175084 ~ Ah, I think I see the problem. Do you know what cell you want from the table? (you can find that with Firebug, for instance) then you could do `e.Row.Cells[0].Text` instead of `Label3.Text`. I just realized you are looking for a label you never explicitly assigned. You could also use the `DataItem` of the `Row` from `e.Row.DataItem` if you wanted to use the value from your datatable instead.

Comment: Note that `e.Row.DataItem` should be cast into a member variable so if you were assigning a class-item (call it Fruit) to the row you would do `Fruit fruit = e.Row.DataItem as Fruit;` or something similar (depending on your choice of language semantics as well) ~ But you're casting to a datatable being returned, so there's no strong class on the individual line item.

Comment: I am trying some things will let you know in a bit

Comment: hey i have one doubt.. how can i make the column invisible for the above

Comment: The problem is that if the columns are generated automatically, you can't. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx) (copied here) `Explicitly declared column fields can be used in combination with automatically generated column fields. When both are used, explicitly declared column fields are rendered first, followed by the automatically generated column fields. Automatically generated column fields are not added to the Columns collection.`

Comment: @user175084 ~ Otherwise, when you `taskTable.Columns.Add("MachineName");` you should instead make a datacolumn (IIRC) and then set the visibility there. You could try enumerating the `Grid.Columns` in Visual Studio with the Intellisense and see if it lets you turn `Visible` on or off.

Answer (score 2):

Do your dynamic edits on GridView1_RowDataBound not on GridView1_DataBound

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label Label3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label3");
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: your fingers were faster, or so it would appear, but I think he doesn't know part of the syntax, see the last row of my post...

Comment: lol, I guess you are faster you just typed more lines than me :)

Comment: Hello, may I know where do you get your avatar? I'm searching sites which provide services like that. Where did you get yours?

Answer (score 1):

Is it blowing up when you're binding the DataSource to the Session object?

```
Grid.DataSource = taskTable;
```

Comment: the above code is working fine... but how do i modify the gridview i get.... i have given example above